# Sign Up form's Password field is populated with login password

Tags: html, forms, passwords

I've a `login` form and a `sign up` form. When I use remember password option on Browser for Login forms, the username and password gets populated on the login form, that is fine.

> But when I try to signup, the sign up form's password field is
>   populated with Login Password, and its above field is populated with
>   UserName(irrespective to the field).

If I change the Signup form's password field Type to "Text". All working fine, the credentials are not pre-filled. But I need to mask the password in signUp form, so I need Type="Password" and don't want the username and password to be prefilled in sign up form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 0):

Give the password fields different names viz. LoginPassword and RegPassword.

Comment: It is working fine, but not sure, why the login username is populated above the Signup forms's password field, while it is named as 'Password'.